# Deregister script on specific user's BuddyPress page

Tags: buddypress, scripts

I run a BuddyPress website and I need to deregister a script on a specific BuddyPress profile page (change avatar to be more specific)

To achieve this I try this code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cutting',100);
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($uri,'/members/'. the_author() .'/profile/change-avatar/') == true){
    function cutting() {
       wp_dequeue_script( 'bp-legacy-js' );
       wp_deregister_script( 'bp-legacy-js' );
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly it's not working :-(

Someone can help me on this one?

EDIT:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cutting',100);

function cutting() {
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($uri,'members/'. the_author() .'profile/change-avatar') == true){
   wp_register_style( 'connected4', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/connected4.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'connected4' );
}
```

}

I guess i must have a trouble with this part

```
if(strpos($uri,'members/'. the_author() .'profile/change-avatar') == true)
```

Comment: The logic should be inside the action callback and remember to prefix it to avoid possible name collisions.

Comment: Thank you Birgire however it's still not working

I tried to enqueue a external stylesheet (more easy to see if snippet is workin) 

I edit my first post.

Comment: Are you sure the handle which you are using to dequeue and deregister does exist? I was checking on latest WordPress and BuddyPress plugin and could not find that handle in core. Please let me know which js file you want to remove? You can find the js file name from the page source when you are on change-avatar page. That would help me provide further inputs.

Comment: Note that `the_author` doesn't return the value, it just echos is @user1437654

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your time! I want to deregister a script from a plugin because it make a conflict with avatar resize tool . Above code are juste exemple to check if my conditionnal is working.

@birgire, i tried also

if(strpos($uri,'members/'. the_author_meta('user_nicename') .'/profile/change-avatar') == true

Comment: Also note the difference between `the_*` and `get_*` functions (echo vs return). Try to print out the value to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally i find the solution using the bp_is_change_avatar

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cutting',100);

function cutting() {
if(bp_is_change_avatar()){
   wp_dequeue_script( 'XXX );

}
}
```

Thank you everybody for your help